# Find and Copy Cell Information

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am attempting to write a script in Google Sheets that will read column D and if the cell  contains, amongst others, the word "Apple" then it will copy the information from the same row in column B to a different sheet in cell(s) C28:C29.

Any help on starting the script would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function myfunc101() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const ssr = 2;
  const srg = ssh.getRange(ssr,1,ssh.getLastRow() - ssr +1,4);
  const svs = srg.getValues();
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('tssid');
  const tsh = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let c28 = [];
  let c29 = [];
  //let d = 0;//add this to delete current row of ssh
  svs.forEach((r,i)=>{
    if(r[3].toString().includes('Apple')) {
      c28.push(r[1]);
      c29.push(r[3]);
      //sh.deleteRow(i+ssr-d++);//add this to delete current row of ssh
    }
  });
  tsh.getRange('C28').setValue(c28.join(', '));
  tsh.getRange('C29').setValue(c29.join(', '));
}
```

if C28 and C29 are merged and you want all of the data in C28 then replace last two lines with: `tsh.getRange('C28').setValue(tsh.getRange('C28').getDisplayValue() + c28.join(', ') + c29.join(', '));`

Comment: Thank you for the script. For further clarification, the sheet I want to copy over to is an already created template and has cells C28 and C29 merged with text already in it. The hope would be for the information from Sheet1 column B information to be added after the text in the merged 28/29 cell. I have amended the OP with pictures as well.

Comment: Well if you merge them then 29 no longer exists and there is only C28 so do you want all of it in C28?

Comment: My apologies, yes all of it in C28

Comment: I added a modification to the code.  If it's not in the format you desire please let me know.

Comment: When I run it, the script will delete the template row-by-row and then pull information from two different places and add it in to C28 and C29.

Comment: The script is not deleting anything now is something you desire?  If so, please see the suggested modification with comments `//add this to delete current row`

Comment: Update: The script, when ran, deletes the template sheet. It is also copying over information from somewhere that isn't column B in the corresponding row that "Apples" is in.